# Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm

### This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\srith.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-bin\6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p\gradle-6.5\lib\gradle-launcher-6.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.5
Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap

---

Check the JVM arguments defined for the gradle process in:

- gradle.properties in project root directory

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was with the Wifi Hotspot was turned on and the daemon was not able to communicate as far as I found